# switch from one hybrid app to another hybrid app using Appium at runtime

Tags: java, android, appium

I want to switch to a different app B while I am in a test session of my app A. The purpose is to send data from app B to app A.  I used startActivity() method to achieve this functionality, but whenever I switch to app B and try to locate the element I am fetching app A element. Please help me on this with example.  Thanks in advance.  * Note: Both applications are hybrid application

Comment: are these iOS apps or android apps?

Comment: @pankajmishra android apps